# Is it possible to define a custom npm registry for visual studio code intellisense/autocompletion?

Tags: node.js, npm, visual-studio-code

we have a custom npm registry (specified via `npm config set registry http://our.url/path`) that also requires a login (`npm login --registry=http://our.url/path`)

VS Code shows auto completion (intellisense) for npm package names when typing in names in package.json's dependencies. It also shows latest versions for those packages there too. However this only works with public released packages.

As we are using a custom npm registry, how to get VS Code to support auto completion for our own npm packages that only have been published on our own registry (including version number)?

Thanks, toebens

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, this is not currently possible, it is hard coded to the official registry in [this file](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/blob/159fa624b2ef3d2b113cc9d23528af65068944c3/extensions/javascript/src/features/packageJSONContribution.ts).

You can open a feature request at https://www.GitHub.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/new

Comment: The file has moved since the answer was posted, however the registry URL is still hard-coded - https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/8e1235ee25e3aad3598ab58016c071b5596b826a/extensions/npm/src/features/packageJSONContribution.ts#L96