# Custom npm registry for vscode's intellisense

Tags: node.js, npm, visual-studio-code

Like this question: [Is it possible to define a custom npm registry for visual studio code intellisense/autocompletion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46113389/is-it-possible-to-define-a-custom-npm-registry-for-visual-studio-code-intellisen)

I'm using a custom npm repository, and I want to be able to use it for the automatic type acquisition features. since this question was asked the entire extension has been refactored. Is it now possible? If it isn't, which repo is it trying to access?

I've tried looking through vscode's settings and the source code, but I haven't found references to configuration or hard coded specific npm repo.